# Architectural templates for 4+1

Tags: architecture

Where can I find a good template for an architecture document that uses a 4+1 paragdim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several tools which have the template for the 4 + 1 architectural view pattern. I currently use StarUML and it serves me well.

But basically, the 4 + 1 view model only states you have five main views to the architecture of your product

1. Logical View: The structure of the system. Class Diagram, Object Diagram
2. Deployment (or Physical) View. Deployment Diagram
3. Use Case View: The *+ 1*. Use Case Diagram
4. Process View: Communication between components of the system. Activity Diagram, Sequence Diagram, Communication Diagram
5. Development (or Component) View. Detailed Class Diagram. Package Diagram

If you can structure your architecture this way, it doesn't matter the tooling you use in generating these diagrams.